# Aggregate Property Value of Corresponding Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have an a set of objects as follows:

```
{"id":136073,"date":"2016-12-13 16:06:55","user":"test1","expt":"ex3","subj":"1481645153775","cond":"Male,Yes","stim":"Peace","resp":0}
{"id":136075,"date":"2016-12-13 16:07:04","user":"test1","expt":"ex3","subj":"1481645035859","cond":"Male,Yes","stim":"Marriage","resp":0}
{"id":136077,"date":"2016-12-13 16:09:55","user":"test1","expt":"ex3","subj":"1481645377779","cond":"Male,Yes","stim":"Alone","resp":0}
{"id":136079,"date":"2016-12-13 16:11:41","user":"test1","expt":"ex3","subj":"1481645377779","cond":"Male,Yes","stim":"Peace","resp":0}
{"id":136145,"date":"2016-12-13 18:49:22","user":"test1","expt":"ex3","subj":"1481654705832","cond":"Male,No","stim":"Alone","resp":-2}
{"id":136147,"date":"2016-12-13 18:49:36","user":"test1","expt":"ex3","subj":"1481654705832","cond":"Male,No","stim":"Peace","resp":0}
{"id":136771,"date":"2016-12-13 22:19:01","user":"test1","expt":"ex3","subj":"1481667464470","cond":"Male,Yes","stim":"Alone","resp":2}
```

I would like to group them into an array called `results`.

I want to aggregate the value of the `resp` property for objects with the same `subj` property value.

What I have doe so far is to create a unique list of subjects to look up and I want to store the sums next to them.

```
for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {

  // console.log(JSON.stringify(results[i].subj))

  if (i>0 && test.includes(results[i].subj)){ 

  } else {  
    var total  = test.push(results[i].subj)
    //  var total2  = test.push(results.resp)
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(test))
  }
}

console.log(test)
```

I have my array of subjects through this.

How do I go about

1- finding all the corresponding resp's

2- summing them

3- storing them next to the subject?

Comment: You don't have an `arrayList` (they don't exist in JavaScript), That's simply a bunch of unrelated object literals.

Comment: aaah I see! thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to advise how I could construct the second array that holds the sums?

Comment: I'm working on it, but it wouldn't be the *second* array as you don't have *any* arrays so far. Again, you have *objects*, which are not *arrays*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hash table for grouping the result.

```js
var results = [{ id: 136073, date: "2016-12-13 16:06:55", user: "test1", expt: "ex3", subj: "1481645153775", cond: "Male,Yes", stim: "Peace", resp: 0 }, { id: 136075, date: "2016-12-13 16:07:04", user: "test1", expt: "ex3", subj: "1481645035859", cond: "Male,Yes", stim: "Marriage", resp: 0 }, { id: 136077, date: "2016-12-13 16:09:55", user: "test1", expt: "ex3", subj: "1481645377779", cond: "Male,Yes", stim: "Alone", resp: 0 }, { id: 136079, date: "2016-12-13 16:11:41", user: "test1", expt: "ex3", subj: "1481645377779", cond: "Male,Yes", stim: "Peace", resp: 0 }, { id: 136145, date: "2016-12-13 18:49:22", user: "test1", expt: "ex3", subj: "1481654705832", cond: "Male,No", stim: "Alone", resp: -2 }, { id: 136147, date: "2016-12-13 18:49:36", user: "test1", expt: "ex3", subj: "1481654705832", cond: "Male,No", stim: "Peace", resp: 0 }, { id: 136771, date: "2016-12-13 22:19:01", user: "test1", expt: "ex3", subj: "1481667464470", cond: "Male,Yes", stim: "Alone", resp: 2 }],
    grouped = [];

results.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.subj]) {
        this[a.subj] = { subj: a.subj, resp: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[a.subj]);
    }
    this[a.subj].resp += a.resp;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `{}` for the results, where the keys are the subject names and the values are the sums. Then enumerate over your list and sum them up. Use `(res[each['subj']] || 0)` to catch the case of new keys.

```
var res = {};
list.forEach(function(each) { 
  res[each['subj']] = (res[each['subj']] || 0) + each['resp']; 
});
console.log(res);
```

This prints

```
{
  "1481645153775": 0,
  "1481645035859": 0,
  "1481645377779": 0,
  "1481654705832": -2,
  "1481667464470": 2
}
```